# Counting characters in a string in Java

Tags: java

Please can I get some help. Much appreciated:

I want to count the number of *s in a line.
When I try to compile the code below

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class StarCount here.
 *
 * @author Damon
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class StarCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int starCount = 0;
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        while(!input.equals("#")){

            for(starCount=0; starCount<=input.length(); starCount++){
                if (input.charAt(starCount).equals('*')){
                    System.out.println(starCount);
                }//if
            }//for

        }//while

    } //main

} // class StarCount
```

But it comes up with

> "char cannot be dereferenced"

I've spent the last 1.5 hours on this and I'm pretty stuck.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests `charAt` returns a char so you need to use `==` to compare the primitive

```
 if (input.charAt(starCount) == '*') {
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (input.charAt(starCount).equals('*')){`

In this line You cannot use equals method for a primitive type like char.

So to compare, you should use == operator.

`if (input.charAt(starCount) == '*'){`